# Enable bold in `algpseudocode` only for specific keywords

Tags: fonts, bold, typewriter

I am new in latex. I want to keep the font type in my algorithmic block but only set the keywords such as `for` and `if` to bold. I am not sure if setting the `ttdefault` inside a algorithm block is the best approach. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage[]{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

% make keywords below bold instead
\newcommand\keywordfont{\ttfamily\bfseries}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{{\keywordfont end}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicdo{{\keywordfont do}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{{\keywordfont while}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{{\keywordfont for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicforall{{\keywordfont for all}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicloop{{\keywordfont loop}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrepeat{{\keywordfont repeat}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicuntil{{\keywordfont until}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{{\keywordfont procedure}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{{\keywordfont function}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{{\keywordfont if}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{{\keywordfont then}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{{\keywordfont else}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{{\keywordfont Require:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{{\keywordfont Ensure:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicreturn{{\keywordfont return}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]

% this may not be the best approach
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\keywordfont{\ttfamily}

    \begin{algorithmic}
        \caption{Gaussian sampler using Taylor series}
        \State sigma $\gets 8 / \sqrt{2  \pi}$ 
        \State variance $\gets$ sigma$^2$
        \State \Comment{returns pdf(x) = standard Gaussian pdf}
        \Function{pdf}{x}
            \Return $e^{(-x^2 / 2)} / \sqrt{2  \pi}$
        \EndFunction
        \State \Comment{returns CDF(z) = standard Gaussian CDF using Taylor approximation}
        \Function{cdf}{x}
            \If{x $<$ -variance}
                \Return 0.0
            \ElsIf{x $>$ variance}
                \Return 1.0
            \EndIf
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that computer modern has no boldface typewriter font. So you have to choose a font family like `lmodern`.

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

To increase the contrast between boldface and normal, you can choose the lightweight series.

```
 \ttfamily\fontseries{l}\selectfont
```

As noted by Werner in the comments, after switching the font it is not necessary to modify the keywords, as they are typeset in boldface anyway (see the code below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage[]{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\let\oldalgorithmic\algorithmic 
\renewcommand\algorithmic{\ttfamily\fontseries{l}\selectfont\oldalgorithmic}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Gaussian sampler using Taylor series}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State sigma $\gets 8 / \sqrt{2  \pi}$ 
        \State variance $\gets$ sigma$^2$
        \State \Comment{returns pdf(x) = standard Gaussian pdf}
        \Function{pdf}{x}
            \Return $e^{(-x^2 / 2)} / \sqrt{2  \pi}$
        \EndFunction
        \State \Comment{returns CDF(z) = standard Gaussian CDF using Taylor approximation}
        \Function{cdf}{x}
            \If{x $<$ -variance}
                \Return 0.0
            \ElsIf{x $>$ variance}
                \Return 1.0
            \EndIf
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically there's no real need to redefine each keyword with the `\keywordfont` font setting in this example. It suffices to use `\let\oldalgorithmic\algorithmic
\renewcommand{\algorithmic}{\ttfamily\fontseries{l}\selectfont\oldalgorithmic}` in the document preamble. Additionally, place the `\caption` inside `algorithm`, not `algorithmic`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, I've modified the answer accordingly.